# how to convert maxsize column within sysfiles dmv to megabytes using T-sql. The maxsize column value is in bytes

Tags: t-sql

I want to convert maxsize column within the sysfiles DMV to Megabytes. By default the column gives the output in no of 8KB pages.

For instance if the value is 131072 then if we convert this value to bytes then it would be 8K*131072 which is 1073741824 bytes.

How can i use this DMV in such a way that the it gives me output directly in MB. Please provide the query for this.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

To convert from 8K pages to MB just divide by 128:

`SELECT *, maxsize/128 AS maxsize_MB FROM sysfiles`